# How do I read the log4j2 logs my HTTPAppender is sending to the url?

Tags: java, spring, http, log4j2

In my `log4j2.xml`, my HTTPAppender is configured to send out the logs to a url on my localhost. I would just like to read the logs whenever my HTTPAppender sends them out. How can I achieve this?

I can see through the console the HTTPAppender is working and logs are going out. Just not sure how to retrieve them after.

`<Http name="Http" url="https://localhost:8080/myUrl/">`

That is the url my log4j2.xml is sending the logs to. What is the easiest way for me to retrieve the logs?

Thanks

Comment: Ehrm, you are just sending them out? I assume something is actually listening on that URL else it would be pretty useless.